# Simple method to retrieve Twitter User Timeline with $http

Tags: angularjs, http, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I need to access a twitter usertimeline with angular...

All keys are correct, it is working with php/curl, but i cannot manage to make it work within angular.  I am using [oauth-signature-js](https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js), then a $http request.   I want to keep it as simple as possible.

The ng-controller :

```
app.controller('twitterController', function($scope, $http){

  // VARIABLES

    var screen_name = 'grapax_be';
    var count = 1;
    var consumer_key                = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var consumer_secret             = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var oauth_access_token          = 'xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var oauth_access_token_secret   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var oauth_timestamp             = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0);
    var oauth_nonce                 = oauth_timestamp;
    var oauth_signature_method      = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    var oauth_version               = '1.0'


  // GENERATE OAUTH SIGNATURE

    var httpMethod = 'GET';
    var url        = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
    var parameters = {
      oauth_consumer_key : consumer_key,
      oauth_token : oauth_access_token,
      oauth_nonce : oauth_nonce,
      oauth_timestamp : oauth_timestamp,
      oauth_signature_method : oauth_signature_method,
      oauth_version : oauth_version,
    };
    var oauth_signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumer_secret, oauth_access_token_secret, { encodeSignature: true });


  // HTTP REQUEST

    var authorization_string = "OAuth " 
            + 'oauth_consumer_key="' + consumer_key + '", '
            + 'oauth_nonce="' + oauth_nonce + '", '
            + 'oauth_signature="' + oauth_signature + '", '
            + 'oauth_signature_method="' + oauth_signature_method + '", '
            + 'oauth_timestamp="' + oauth_timestamp + '", '
            + 'oauth_token="' + oauth_access_token + '", '
            + 'oauth_version="' + oauth_version + '"';

    $http.jsonp('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json', {
        headers: {'Authorization': authorization_string},
        params:{
            count: count,
            screen_name: screen_name
        }
      }).success(function(res){ console.log('res:', res) });

});
```

This is still giving me a error 400.

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kF9iqCOv31ZXuuy4vlSp)

Any tips, questions, remarks, are welcome....
Thank you!

Johan

Comment: Can you share a plunker? If not, can you put here the CURL (you can get this from chrome network console)

Comment: @pablorsk Here is a plunker :  https://plnkr.co/edit/kF9iqCOv31ZXuuy4vlSp
When i was speaking of the php/curl, i was just mentioning that the keys provided (consumer, secret, ...) where working in another environment (php).    Cheerz!

Comment: I have answered my own question, and included the php/cURL method i use.  It would be nice if you can mark it as useful if you find it so... Cheerz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Own further answer:

1. Headers cannot be set in jsonp request.
2. Using Apache/WP at server side, it was just better to stick with a
   php/cURL request, and calling it with a simple $http.get()
   for Angular integration.

By the way this PHP/cURL method is working
    great :
    http://iag.me/socialmedia/build-your-first-twitter-app-using-php-in-8-easy-steps/

Answer (score 1):

Headers cannot be set in jsonp request. One solution can be to implement this using http client on server rather than the browser.

Comment: OK i understand now i should avoid using the browser for security reasons.  I am using Angular on top of a Wordpress/Apache server.  Does this mean that i should keep using php/curl in this case for http request, so not use Angular for this task ?

Comment: It depends on security framework in place. In this scenario where jsonp is used for authentication, javascript in general will not be able solve the problem.

Comment: I have answered my own question, which is just an extension of yours.  It would be nice if you can mark it as useful if you find it so :)  Thank you.